# Dropbox Core API >10000 file move strategy

Tags: python, python-2.7, dropbox, dropbox-api

I synced my iPhoto library which has around 50,000 files to a Dropbox folder, but want to move it to a different folder. When I tried to move the folder through dropbox.com, it says "too many files, use desktop app". So I instead installed dropbox for python (pip install dropbox) and setup the code as in the tutorial and ran:

```
db_client2.file_move('/Personal Pictures/iPhoto Library', '/temp/iPhoto Library')
```

As listed in the docs, there is a 10,000 file size limit:

```
dropbox.rest.ErrorResponse: [406] u'There are too many files involved in this operation.'
```

What strategy have you guys used for moving a single folder with that many files?

Comment: ... why do you not want to use the native application? But ignoring that, if your content isn't already in smaller folders inside the primary one that you can move individually, then your only option would I imagine be to batch-move the files manually.

Comment: If the files are no longer available locally, will you have to re-download (sync) the folder before you can "move" it to a new location?

Answer (score 0):

This solution is "slow", but can go unattended:

```
files= list_files(db_client2, path_prefix='/Personal Pictures/iPhoto Library', include_media_info=True)

for k, v in files.iteritems():
    final_path = k.replace('/personal pictures/', '/temp/')
    if v['is_dir'] == True:
        print k + " is a dir and is skipped"
    else:
        db_client2.file_move(k, final_path)
        print "moved " + k
```